# why is there no poll/select like mechanism for message queue?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Like we can do, poll/epoll/select on an fd, we can not on msg queue id. I found some non standard methods to make msgqueue-id to fd, but afterall its a non standard. So my question is, Why linux geeks, not implemented poll/select on msg queue id ? Does that lead to serious issue ?

I need to implement such sort of mechanism. How can I do that ?

Comment: What compelling reason do you have for using sysv MQs?  There are a few but if you aren't using them there is no reason to be using sysv implementation.

Comment: Hello mate. Did you get any progress in your question? I am using a PowerPC 2.4 kernel that has no POSIX queues and I'd like to be able to use `select()` on it either.

Comment: [TooLateComment] You lost me somewhere: you are asking for a Linux-only solution, though you know there is a Linux-only solution, but you don't like it, as it is Linux-only.

Answer (score 18):

From the [`mq_overview`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html) man page:

> Polling message queue descriptors
>
> On Linux, a message queue descriptor is actually a file descriptor, and can be
>          monitored using select(2), poll(2), or epoll(7).  This is not portable.

So you *can* use `poll` and friends on message queues - just make sure you use the modern variant.

Comment: thnx for the reply, but I was talking about sys-V message queues. and u are abt posix msg queues.

Answer (score 4):

As Mat points out, POSIX MQs *can* be used with `select/poll` in Linux.  Beyond that, [mq_notify()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/mq_notify.3.html) provides you with the options to receive a signal or spawn a new thread when an empty MQ receives a message.  This is another means to avoid blocking or polling.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that it doesn't just work, but if it doesn't, I suspect the reason is to avoid encouraging such a non-portable practice. While message queue descriptors are allowed to be file descriptors, they're not required to be, and code that assumes they're file descriptors (and thus occupy the same "numberspace") is non-portable.

If you need file descriptors, you'd probably be better off just using Unix sockets or some other mechanism in place of message queues. Message queues seem to be intended for use with real-time programming with threads where `select`/`poll`-based event-driven IO is generally not used.

Answer (score 1):

The SysV MsgQ gives you provision to block your msgrcv() call  for a particular message type or for any message type using IPC_WAIT. Poll/epoll/select are used to help you write a event-driven program in which the user application doesn't waste cpu cycles polling for a particular event and leaves it to the better judgement of the kernel. This is what you can also achieve using the SysV msg Q.

Answer (score 0):

IBM AIX has extension for poll() on System V queues. But Linux does not have this feature. On the other hand, Linux Posix queue implementation allows to select/poll/epoll on queues.